# Ist es richtig, wenn das -e im sprachlichen Gebrauch des Imperativs oft fallen gelassen wird?

Tags: grammar, pronunciation

Bsp. Gespräch:

> Person1: "Ich möchte meinem Opa persönlich zum Geburtstag gratulieren, aber kann nicht zu ihm fahren."
>   Person2: "Schreib ihm doch einen handgeschriebenen Brief."

Wenn Person2 "Schreib..." sagt, wäre da nicht "Schreibe..." die korrekte Form? Oder sind beide Formen akzeptabel, nur dass sie eine andere Intensität vermitteln?

Comment: Bist Du sicher, dass Dein Beispiel den Fall abdeckt, den Du meinst? Du gibst hier einen Imperativ an, der tatsächlich beide Formen annehmen kann. Häufig wird in gesprochenem Deutsch aber auch in der 1. Person Sg. die Endung fallengelassen: "Ich schreib' ihm doch jede Woche!" -- "Achso, das wusst' ich doch nicht." Meinst Du das (auch)?

Comment: Ich glaube ich meine schon den Imperativ, denn das andere Beispiel ist ja falsch, oder? Und sind im Imperativ wirklich beide formen komplett gleichgestellt - kein Unterschied?

Comment: Dann würde ich vorschlagen, den Bezug auf den Imperativ im Titel hinzuzufügen.

Comment: RafaelCichocki, Welches andere Beispiel soll falsch sein? Das Beispiel von @elena? Es ist falsch, wenn du eine Bewerbung oder eine Doktorarbeit schreibst, aber in der Umgangssprache ist's einfach 'normal'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im Fall von schreib/schreibe ist bummis Antwort völlig korrekt. So sieht es in der Tat für die meisten Verben aus.

Wikipedia schreibt dazu [im Artikel über den Imperativ](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperativ_%28Modus%29#Bildung_des_Imperativs):

> Die Endung -e beim Imperativ Singular ist im heutigen Sprachgebrauch meistens fakultativ: mach! und mache! oder schlaf und schlafe gelten in Deutschland als gleichwertige Parallelformen, in Österreich ist das Endungs-e im Hochdeutschen unüblich und veraltet. Bei den schwachen Verben, deren Wortstamm auf -t oder -d endet, gilt die Form mit -e als stilistisch besser (warte! und rede! anstatt wart! und red!). Bei Verben wie rechnen oder atmen, bei denen aus dem Wortstamm ein e entfällt (siehe Rechen(-regel), Atem) ist die Imperativform mit der Endung -e, also rechne!, die einzig mögliche Variante. Bei Verben auf -eln und -ern muss zum Wortstamm ohne die Endung -st ebenfalls ein -e angefügt werden: wandere!; bei den Verben auf -eln kann außerdem das e im Wortstamm entfallen: sammele! oder sammle! Starke Verben mit Vokalwechsel im Imperativ können kein -e als Endung bekommen, es heißt nur: wirf!, gib!, iss!.

Comment: Man setzt auch (inzwischen?) keine Apostrophe (mehr) bei Imperativen ohne „-e“, z.B. „Schreib!“.

Comment: Praktisch gibt es in der Umgangssprache keine starken Imperative mehr. Die große Mehrzahl zumindest der jüngeren Leute sagt _werf_, _geb_, _eß_.

Answer (score 2):

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schreiben) sind beide Formen gleichgestellt.